# Ugly App Engine login consent screen

Tags: google-app-engine, google-signin

I'm using App Engine's UserService which is extremely handy programming-wise, but I've gotten fed up of looking at its consent screen. I'm not sure what the trigger is but I have to click 'Allow' every so often.

I'm referring to this:
[image: ugly consent screen]
Worst feature of it is it doesn't look good at all on mobile.

Is there a way to get this one instead?:
[image]

At this point I don't mind writing new code and give up UserService. At the end of the day I just need the email-address to authenticate someone. But I would assume UserService should be capable of this, right?

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to do this but not with userService which unfortunately hasnt been updated in years.

look at the official docs on login with the Google+ button (using a public webpage without appengine native authentication) so you handle it yourself by getting access token and such:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

also look at the google identity toolkit. they relaunched it recently and supports login with lots of other providers not just google.
this is likely your best option because all you need is authentication (their email or identifier) but you don't need permissions (which the former option handles with scopes):
https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/

Answer (score 0):

If you're having users connect directly to your App Engine application and are using the built in security/user methods then you'll be stuck with the App Engine authentication screen.

If you wanted to use the nicer looking consent screen you could switch over to use a Google Endpoint style system where by you host the front end separate from the back end and use API client tokens to have the two sides communicate.

I'm in the processes of migrating from a purely App Engine hosted application to an App Engine front end talking to a App Engine back end via End Points. This allows me to use nicer consent screens and service both the front end and back end from the same application. I have done this with both a Javascript and Java front end and I assume there are ways to do this with Python given the number of available libraries.

Comment: but no need to use endpoints. its just like implementing a login with the g+ button ( or identity toolkit) on a web page.